# Resize Table Header height according to other Table Header height in different div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a specification area on my webpage just like I've shown in this **[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/jz1fakx8/)**. I am not able to understand how can we make left div and right div table header **height** equal to each other, because each section in left div's table header height may differ as per the characters inserted in the right div table header. The code is given below:

```css
#maindiv {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:565px;
    color:Black;
}
#leftdiv {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:5px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}
#leftdiv table {
    padding:5px;
    font-size:22px;
}
#rightdiv {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-top:0px;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:67%;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}
#rightdiv table {
    padding:5px;
    font-size:22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
    <div id="leftdiv">
        <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Product Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Size Available</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Color Available</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Product Description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Availability</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="rightdiv">
         <table align="left" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Cell Phone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>5.5,6.5</th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>White, Red, Black, Silver, Gold</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>QWERTY Soft Keyboard (Google Keyboard and Swiftkey Pre-loaded), USB OTG Support, 24 Languages Support, Wi-Fi Direct, WLAN Support, Games, Vibrant</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>This product is not out of stock.</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you use a single table with two columns?

Comment: @TinoMThomas I can't do that, because I have styled my rightdiv with background image according to products and it has some different tweeks as well. I've just posted a small part from my script here so basically I have to use two different div's only and cannot merge my tables with two columns to make it a single table.

Comment: Added a revised answer based on this new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

OP has since specified he can't just make one table.

How about using JQuery to match heights. Ugly but it works (my life story).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4hxo0xj/)

Fix table layout:

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Give each row a unique ID

```
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th id="leftrow1">Product Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="leftrow2">Size Available</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="leftrow3">Color Available</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="leftrow4">Product Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th id="leftrow5">Availability</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Match them up:

```
$("#leftrow1").height($("#rightrow1").height());
$("#leftrow2").height($("#rightrow2").height());
$("#leftrow3").height($("#rightrow3").height());
$("#leftrow4").height($("#rightrow4").height());
$("#leftrow5").height($("#rightrow5").height());
```

There's probably something more elegant than this which I'd love to see.

**OLD ANSWER**

Just merge the two tables into one table as follows:

```
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <td>Cell Phone<</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Size Available</th>
    <td>5.5,6.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Color Available</th>
    <td>White, Red, Black, Silver, Gold</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Description</th>
    <td>QWERTY Soft Keyboard (Google Keyboard and Swiftkey Pre-loaded), USB OTG Support, 24 Languages Support, Wi-Fi Direct, WLAN Support, Games, Vibrant</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Availability</th>
    <td>This product is not out of stock.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/em82kq9m/1/)

Comment: That's perfectly what I was looking ahead for mate